# How to take just the key that contains value in laravel collection?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this array(collection):

```
$collect = collect([
    'governorate_id' => $request->governorate_id,
    'area_id' => $request->area_id,
]);
```

I need to take just the one that contains value in request and ignore the other one( like when the `governorate_id` is full ignore the `area_id` and reverse).

```
$collect = collect([
    'governorate_id' => $request->governorate_id,
    'area_id' => $request->area_id,
]);

$collect->each(function ($item, $key) {

    // do something..

});
dd for $collect :

 Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1395 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
        "governorate_id" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "2"
        1 => "3"
        ]
        "area_id" => null
    ]
}
```

Comment: what if both have empty or not empty values ?

Comment: @Ersoy No it will be just one always and make a validation before it means always one of them has should be filled !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will return the non-empty "valued" key-value pairs.

```
$collect->filter()
    ->each(function ($value, $key) use ($group) {
        // group-user relationship actions...
        $users = User::whereIn($key, $value)->get();
        $group->users()->attach($users);
    });
```

Tried with both combinations.

```
collect(['area_id' => '122', 'governorate_id' => '']);
collect(['area_id' => '', 'governorate_id' => 123]);
```

Comment: After "reject" can I use the value for doing something!

Comment: if you just need value i think you may use `first` it will return only value. i am adding as second alternative. @jamel

Comment: I need both of them key and value then loop to the value via each

Comment: pls  take a look at my question again I updated! ( the idea is I need to take the value and loop them after ignore the empty one )

Comment: @jamel loop what, sum ? append ? Please update the the question and post the expected value and i will update the answer

Comment: Loop on the like in governorate ids loop on the ids and store it in database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217160/discussion-between-ersoy-and-jamel).